# Can strcmp() work with strings in c++?

Tags: c++, string, strcmp

I have this line of code

```
if(strcmp(ob[i].getBrand(), ob[j].getBrand()) > 0)
```

and I get this error

> error C2664: 'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'

Does that mean that strcmp doesnt work with strings, but instead it has to convert it to char?

Comment: You don't have to convert anything. Just use the `std::string::c_str()` member function.

Comment: You could do that if you have to use strcmp. I prefer Mark Garcia's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `strcmp`. Use `std::string::compare` which has the same behavior as `strcmp`.

```
if(ob[i].getBrand().compare(ob[j].getBrand()) > 0)
```

Or much better

```
if(ob[i].getBrand() > ob[j].getBrand())
```

Generally you should use `std::string::compare` when you have to test various cases where the strings will be different, e.g.

```
auto cmp = ob[i].getBrand().compare(ob[j].getBrand());

if(cmp == 0) ...
else if(cmp > 0) ...
else if(cmp < 0) ...
```

In this way you only have to do the comparison operation on the strings once.

However, in your case where it's somehow apparent that you only have to use the comparison result in a single case (I'm really assuming, as I don't know the context of the code given), then `operator >` will suffice, and is much easier on the eye (the brain!).

Comment: The compare function actually comes from char_traits, and of course for std::string, compare will call the compare function of char_traits<char>. This means you can use different char_traits implementations to handle different comparisons (that might work differently from strcmp in some cases). 

Incidentally it uses memcmp not strcmp and thus I'm not sure if it's exactly the same if the string has negative chars.

Answer (score 6):

If `getBrand()`  gives a `std::string`  just use `>` compare.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `.c_str()` to convert a `string` to char array, then you are able to use strcmp().

But in your case, use `>` is better :)